# focus works in componentDidUpdate but not in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I read similar questions but I think my situation is a little bit different. First of all, I am using React 15 and I have two components (parent and child).

I reach the input element in a plain JavaScript way and focus on it in componentDidUpdate, however, componentDidMount doesn't work. When I log out the element, I can see the correct element in the console.

Parent Component

```
 componentDidMount(){
        console.log(document.getElementById('abc')) // logs the correct element
        document.getElementById('abc').focus(); // DOES NOT work
    }

  componentDidUpdate(){
        document.getElementById('abc').focus(); // works
    }
```

Child Component

```
<input autofocus={true} name="search" id="abc" type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `ref`

Your Parent Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.input.focus()
}

<ChildComponent inputRef={node => (this.input = node)} />
```

Your Child Component:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ inputRef }) => (
  <input name="search" ref={inputRef} type="text"/>
)
```

Comment: if you go the refs route you'll have to use `React.forwardRef()`

Comment: @Derek you're correct. `React.forwardRef` was added in v16.3.0 but the OP is using React 15.